# Preprocessing files before upload to FTP

Tags: javascript, php, git, phpstorm

I'm using phpStorm to develop and I want to process some files before it's uploaded to the FTP server.

For example, I want to strip all comments on PHP files or even compress/obfuscate it, or minify css and js.

I know that there are some plugins to minify css and js, but I don't want to do this over my local files, I just want to upload it processed, but leave untouched my files.

I'm currently using Git, so when I commit a change, all affected files are automatically uploaded to the FTP server. It could be great to commit the changes, process the files and upload the result to the FTP server.

Answer (score 2):

> It could be great to commit the changes, process the files and upload the result to the FTP server.

That would mean, in a [**post-commit** hook](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks):

- update a separate repo
- change your files in that separate repo
- sftp the separate repo content

In other words, you would upload a processed working tree from *another* local repo, and *not* from your current local repo (where you don't want to change your files).

Comment: But, the process to upload to FTP is done by phpStorm. So, the preprocessing must be done by phpStorm.

Comment: @Juanjico so can't you commit to a first repo, and update the second repo which is managed by phpStorm, meaning phpStorm would do the preprocessing there?